# Eliminate duplicates of records in the column on JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

**Example of initial data:**

```
  Table 1                                             Table 2
|  ID   |   Name   |  Cost   |  Cost2  |           |  ID   |   Info1   |   Info2   |
|-------|----------|---------|---------|           |-------|-----------|-----------|
|  1    |   Name1  |   20    |   50    |           |  1    |   text1   |   text1   |
|  2    |   Name2  |   30    |   10    |           |  1    |   text1   |   text1   |
|  2    |   Name22 |   30    |   40    |           |  1    |   text1   |   text1   |
|  3    |   Name3  |   20    |   50    |           |  2    |   text21  |   text21  |
|  4    |   Name4  |   30    |   70    |           |  2    |   text22  |   text22  |
                                                   |  2    |   text23  |   text23  |
                                                   |  2    |   text24  |   text24  |
```

In my initial data I have relationship between 2 tables by field **ID**. I need to join second table to the first one.
So this is simple result of `Leftjoin` by `table1.ID` = `table2.ID`

```
|  ID   |   Name   |  Cost   |  Cost2  |   Info1   |   Info2   |  
|-------|----------|---------|---------|-----------|-----------|                                                   
|  1    |   Name1  |   20    |   50    |   text1   |   text1   |                                                   
|  1    |   Name1  |   20    |   50    |   text1   |   text1   |  
|  1    |   Name1  |   20    |   50    |   text1   |   text1   |  
|  2    |   Name2  |   30    |   10    |   text21  |   text21  |  
|  2    |   Name2  |   30    |   10    |   text22  |   text22  |  
|  2    |   Name2  |   30    |   10    |   text23  |   text23  | 
|  2    |   Name2  |   30    |   10    |   text24  |   text24  |
|  2    |   Name22 |   60    |   40    |   text21  |   text21  | 
|  2    |   Name22 |   60    |   40    |   text22  |   text22  | 
|  2    |   Name22 |   60    |   40    |   text23  |   text23  | 
|  2    |   Name22 |   60    |   40    |   text24  |   text24  |
```

How I can get result without dublication by `join` on fields (Cost, Cost2)

**Expected result:**

```
|  ID   |   Name   |  Cost   |  Cost2  |   Info1   |   Info2   |  
|-------|----------|---------|---------|-----------|-----------|                                                   
|  1    |   Name1  |   20    |   50    |   text1   |   text1   |                                                   
|  1    |   Name1  |  NULL   |  NULL   |   text1   |   text1   |  
|  1    |   Name1  |  NULL   |  NULL   |   text1   |   text1   |  
|  2    |   Name2  |   30    |   10    |   text21  |   text21  |  
|  2    |   Name2  |  NULL   |  NULL   |   text22  |   text22  |  
|  2    |   Name2  |  NULL   |  NULL   |   text23  |   text23  | 
|  2    |   Name2  |  NULL   |  NULL   |   text24  |   text24  |
|  2    |   Name22 |   30    |   40    |   text21  |   text21  | 
|  2    |   Name22 |  NULL   |  NULL   |   text22  |   text22  | 
|  2    |   Name22 |  NULL   |  NULL   |   text23  |   text23  | 
|  2    |   Name22 |  NULL   |  NULL   |   text24  |   text24  |
```

Comment: You could try using distinct when you query with the join.  Would that properly solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `row_number` window function make row number in subquery then get `Cost` and `Cost2` by `CASE WHEN`, which row number is `1`

```
SELECT ID,
    Name,
    CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Cost end, 
    CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Cost2 end,  
    Info1,
    Info2      
FROM (
    SELECT  
       t1.ID,
       Name,
       Cost,
       Cost2,
       Info1,
       Info2,   
       row_number() over(partition by Name order by Info1) rn
    FROM Table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
) t1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0998ae59bf74f4722e2d989f1bf388bc)

Answer (score 1):

You need a "line number" for the `join`.  Your tables don't have one, but you can add one in using `row_number()`:

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id,
       t1.name, t1.cost, t2.info1, t2.info2
       . . .
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) full join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

You don't, alas, get the `name` using this method.  But that makes sense.  It is only in `table1`, so it should not be on every matching row.

EDIT:

That is not exactly right.  You want the rows repeated.  And then values not to appear.  I think this is conditional logic:

If you really do need it:

```
select t1.id, t1.name,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by (select null)) = 1 then cost END) as Cost,
       t2.info1, t2.info2
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id ;
```

Comment: thank you for answer, it's great. if i had the opportunity to accept both answer, I would definitely do it. If it possible please edit case expression, it is not ended here.